# How to compile QEMU for 64 bit

Tags: compilation, makefile, qemu

i'm trying to comlpile qemu source code for 64 bit ,but it is being compiled in 32 bit ..

These are the commands which i'm using

---

```
#!/bin/bash

 cd qemu-1.6.0\

 export
 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/glib/lib/pkgconfig:`pwd`/../suu
 pport_libs/libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig export CFLAGS="-mabi=64"


 QEMU_CFLAGS="-mabi=64" sudo ./configure
 --prefix=`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/qemuu  --target-list=mips64-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-fdt --with-coroutine=sigaltss tack --extra-cflags="-I`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/glib/include/glib-2.0/"


sudo make && sudo make install
```

---

i'm saving it in a file named "build.sh" and running this script as "./build.sh"

Any help would be Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing script as `./build.sh` the environments you export will be to the child shell sessions but when you give `sudo make` in the script it will not inherit the exported variables.

change the script a little bit by removing `sudo` for `make` and `make install` and run the script as `sudo`

```
#!/bin/bash

 cd qemu-1.6.0\

 export
 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/glib/lib/pkgconfig:`pwd`/../suu
 pport_libs/libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig export CFLAGS="-mabi=64"


 QEMU_CFLAGS="-mabi=64" sudo ./configure
 --prefix=`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/qemuu  --target-list=mips64-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-fdt --with-coroutine=sigaltss tack --extra-cflags="-I`pwd`/../support_libs/libs/glib/include/glib-2.0/"


 make && make install
```

now run script as

```
sudo ./build.sh
```

Comment: Thanku very much for ur time.. but now when i'm compiling it's showing a error in :tcg-op.h" file. here is the error                                                                  -------------------------------------------------------------------   In file included from /home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/tcg/tcg.h:117:0,
                 from /home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/exec.c:29:
/home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/tcg/tcg-op.h:26:1: error: expected identifier before ‘int’
make[1]: *** [exec.o] Error 1